# "Cut & Paste" Row from one Table to another inside Access DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, visual-studio-2017

I've built a simple application in Visual Studio 2017 , but have become stuck.

The idea is, take an Access Database with 4 identical Tables. 
We call the Tables: "Active-Lead-List","Send-Info","Not-Interested","Removed"

Load "Active-Lead-List" Table with 5000 rows of Records.

This application will be used to Display the "Active-Lead-List Table" Data, 1 Row/Record/"Lead" at a time.

The app user would click for example "Send-Info" and subsequently this would "Cut" the corresponding row from the currently displayed "Active-Lead-List" Table and "Paste" that row/columns in another table "Send-Info" Table.

I've managed to get data to import/display properly, Next and Previous button for going to next/prev. Record in the Table functions properly..

But cannot for the life of me figure out how to approach this seemingly simple yet provingly painful job of "Cut & Paste"!

Here are some images of my project:

Here is all the code I've done so far. To Fill the Form when initially loaded, and the Next and Previous button functions are all i've done and DO operate as intended.

These are the desired functions of the UI

All I need to do, is be able to move the current record being displayed, to either of the other Tables ( "Not-Interested" or "Send-Info" ) and this project will be complete for now. Obviously the Delete and Save functions too, but I desperately need this solution asap and seriously plan to invest time and $ to properly learn these programming languages and eventually re-build entirely with many more features and running on a localized server in our office as suggested before. You guys and gals are really helping me learn, fast. I've digested a wealth of knowledge here already! THANKS!!

Comment: Why the need to create multiple tables when you could simply set a Status field, e.g. Active, Suspended etc? You will only need to update one field instead of "moving" rows around tables.

Comment: Would this be effective for keeping Data completely separate? Figured separate Tables under one Database would be effective but I have zero knowledge!

Comment: Well, in order to move records from one table to another, you'll have to import to table B and delete from table A. Repeating this action will "grow" your Access database file significantly and you'll have to perform a *"Compact & Repair"* often to avoid errors.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much for the clarity there. This is a temporary solution, I hope to create a more sustainable solution for this in the near future. It will need to be server based and accessible by several local PCs in office setting. But that's the future. Could you point me in the right direction for Importing  a row/all columns into a new table and deleting the original source table row/reocord

Comment: You can do that as per @aendeerei answer below. Create two queries, one to import and one to delete which both take an *ID* as a parameter. Then execute both queries by passing the *ID* of the record you want to move.

Comment: @Markman88, Kostas is right: By updating one value in a status field, you would really have an optimal and very simple solution. When I wrote my answer I didn't take the problem's semantics into consideration. So, the comment of Kostas should be the most suited answer to your question. Good remark, Kostas. Now you have at least two perspectives to learn from, Markmann ;-)

Comment: @Markman88 If you need to move to a server in the future, take into consideration MySQL (as db server), and a web solution like Apache (as web server) + PHP (as full featured programming language and scripting engine). Don't use any desktop solution, like Access, in the future, because is hard to maintain such a system when there are more than 3-4 users. For example, when you make changes on your .exe file, then you have to deploy it to all users "per hand". When you use a web solution, then you make changes on the server, and they are automatically and instantly usable by all users.

Comment: @Markman88 And I really recommend you to not use bundle solutions like MAMP, XAMP, WAMP, etc. Try to install each component of your future software system (Apache, MySQL, PHP) per hand. Because, when you do this, you have the big chance to learn by doing and recherches in web.

Comment: Do follow the advice from @KostasK. There would be just about zero reasons for proceeding with your current "moving-records" concept.

Comment: @Gustav, it's not completely true, if you are reffering yourself from a general point of view. I, personally had a big project in which it made a lot of sense to run simultaneous import/delete processes on identical (very big) data packages. Actually it was the only viable solution for a given time. It's not always about what solution is the best. The resources play a big role in different decisions, too.

Comment: @aendeerei: Yes, I agree, that's why I wrote _just about_. There will always be cases calling for creative solutions like yours. But setting a client _Active/Suspended_ is probably not among these.

Comment: @Gustav Do I see a little trace of irony in your answer, or am I interpreting your reference point in a false way? Because my solution presented in my answer to Markmann88 was really not creative. The _Active/Suspended_ one is ;-) I just wrote code without taking the best, optimal solution into consideration. Because I didn't realised the semantic sense of "_Suspended Billing_" process - as I wrote somewhere upper in the comments...

Comment: @Gustav If you were reffering yourself to the solution of my earlier project, then... that was also not the "creative" one. But it was the best one in that given conditions. About "_just about_", you're right. My mistake.

Comment: @aendeerei: It was a general comment only. By "creative" I mean those kind of work-arounds or the like, we all have to do from time to time and, when taken out of context, may seem weird, foolish, or even stupid to others. Very little is black/white.

Comment: @Gustav Oh, ok. Sorry, I read it 7 times and it had the same sense for me any time :-) Nothing personal. Now I understand your point. Yes, we have to apply tips and tricks sometimes :-) And I think they are the soul of learning and acquiring knowledge in our field of work. Very rare runs a piece of code smooth, from the first try. Then we search, we find, we read and apply :-) Have a nice day, Gustav.

Comment: Thank You everyone for all of your excellent feedback. I am currently looking into this further, as I discovered even though Aendeerei provided a great solution, one factor i didn't consider is: The application is used to show 1 "client"/Record/row at a time. User can click "suspended billing" as mentioned before, or a few other buttons which would move the client from "ActiveClients" Table to the appropriate one (Suspended, etc). I will need to identify the currently displayed ID of the Row/Client and call that to be Inserted into other Table and Deleted from ActiveClient Table (Source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updating/transfering codes:

---

### (1) Code for updating "send_info" field:

```
Private Sub btnSENDINFO_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSENDINFO.Click

    ' Define variables.
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("...")
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim leadId As String

    ' Read id value from the form control.
    leadId = txtIDbox.Text

    ' Define command for updating send_info field in active_leads.
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE active_leads SET send_info = TRUE WHERE id = " & leadId

    conn.Open()

    ' Run queries.
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ' Close connection.
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

---

### (2) Code for updating "not_interested" field:

```
Private Sub btnNOTINTERESTED_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNOTINTERESTED.Click

    ' Define variables.
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("...")
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim leadId As String

    ' Read id value from the form control.
    leadId = txtIDbox.Text

    ' Define command for updating not_interested field in active_leads.
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE active_leads SET not_interested = TRUE WHERE id = " & leadId

    ' Open connection.
    conn.Open()

    ' Run queries.
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ' Close connection.
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

---

### (3) Code for transfering an active lead to `removed_leads`:

```
Private Sub btnREMOVE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnREMOVE.Click

    ' Define variables.
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("...")
    Dim cmd1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim cmd2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim leadId As String

    ' Read id value from the form control.
    leadId = txtIDbox.Text

    ' Define command for inserting an active lead into removed_leads.
    cmd1.Connection = conn
    cmd1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO removed_leads (active_lead_id, business_name, street_address, phone, reviews, website, email, send_info, not_interested)
                        SELECT al.id, al.business_name, al.street_address, al.phone, al.reviews, al.website, al.email, al.send_info, al.not_interested
                        FROM active_leads AS al
                        WHERE al.id = " & leadId

    ' Define command for deleting an active lead from active_leads.
    cmd2.Connection = conn
    cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd2.CommandText = "DELETE FROM active_leads WHERE id = " & leadId

    ' Open connection.
    conn.Open()

    ' Run queries.
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ' Close connection.
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

### Useful links:

Here are some links you'll need:

- [**How to use BindingSource and BindingNavigator**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVZPTzkQOcY)
- [**How to: Bind Windows Forms Controls with the BindingSource Component
  Using the Designer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bind-wf-controls-with-the-bindingsource)
- [The Connection Strings Reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)
- [Perform updates and inserts using TableAdapters or Command
  objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/insert-new-records-into-a-database)
- [Update data by using a Table​Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/update-data-by-using-a-tableadapter)
- [Create and configure TableAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-and-configure-tableadapters)
- [Fill datasets by using TableAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters)
- [Creating Event Handlers in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dacysss4(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [How to: Navigate Data in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b63ha24w(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Data Sources Supported by Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3y6cb0c(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/data-type-summary)
- [Visual Basic Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/)
- [How to: Navigate Data in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-navigate-data-in-windows-forms)
- [Data types for Access desktop databases](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Data-types-for-Access-desktop-databases-df2b83ba-cef6-436d-b679-3418f622e482)
- [Introduction to data types and field properties](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c)
- [When to use which data type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#whentousetype)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146389/discussion-on-answer-by-aendeerei-cut-paste-row-from-one-table-to-another-in).